# Is it possible to do a Masters dissertation at a different university?

Tags: thesis, masters, united-kingdom

I am currently enrolled in a masters program and am struggling to complete my dissertation as I have no real interest in what I am doing and have lost my motivation. I have completed all my coursework to allow me to gain a PGDip and would like to know if it is possible to transfer and my complete my dissertation at another university in the United kingdom?

Comment: Why would doing your dissertation at a different university make the situation better? It seems to me that most possible motivations (e.g. being nearer to family, having a different living environment, etc) may be met by asking a different question: "Can I find a way to complete my dissertation at my current university while also doing X/Y/Z?" The answer is often yes, if you can find a supervisor who is sympathetic to your needs and willing to work with you to find a mutually acceptable solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consult your university regulations as well as your department for advice on this. My gut instinct would be that it *should* be possible, but you need to make sure you follow the appropriate rules. I can just about guarantee that you'll need to find someone at your home university who will be willing to act as the "internal" supervisor for your thesis.

However, the possibility of being able to do it and actually surmounting the obstacles and being able to do it are quite different. It can be very hard to get another research group outside of your "home" university to be willing to take you on short term as a master's student—primarily because they probably have no idea who you are, and how reliable a student you will be. Nobody really wants to take a risk on a completely unknown quantity based on a "cold call" email.

So your best bet would be to work with the faculty in your department to find somewhere else to do your research.

Comment: has summed up everything important. I just want to point something that you might want to consider. If you are lucky some of your current supervisor(s) have some former students working in another university; If you somehow get a good recommendation from your current supervisor they would accept you. On the other hand, if you are trying to "get rid" of your current supervisor and group altogether, hope that you had some ties with someone who has a former student working in another university